# How to set log level in go test?

Tags: testing, go, glog

Hi I am running my unit tests by using:
`godep go test -v -run TestMyCode`,

but I did not find a way to show my info logs in my tests:

```
glog.V(4).Infof("Adding new pods from source %s : %v", source, update.Pods)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can log your messages to console by setting few flags. Try the below code in the init() function.

```
flag.Set("alsologtostderr", fmt.Sprintf("%t", true))
var logLevel string
flag.StringVar(&logLevel, "logLevel", "4", "test")
flag.Lookup("v").Value.Set(logLevel)
```